# Regex to match string which should not begin or end with specific characters

Tags: regex

I need a regex to avoid strings which start or end with '+' and '-'.
Here is my expression:

```
^[^+-]*[^+-]$
```

Is this correct? Looks like it's working but I didn't test it property so I'm not sure.

Comment: So you just want us to test your work for you?

Comment: What do you mean you 'didn't test it properly'? Go and test it properly then, posting on SO doesn't count as testing. Here's a website that might help you quickly test things http://regexr.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
^(?![+-]).*(?![+-]).$

^(?![+-])  ### assert that the first character is not "+" or "-"
.*         ### match any character zero or more times
(?![+-]).$ ### assert that the last character is not "+" or "-"
```

You can try the regex here :
https://regex101.com/r/ZxguTc/1

Answer (score -1):

Yours is incorrect. Try running it on online regex testing websites.

Use something like this

https://regex101.com/r/cPf4Ym/1

```
^[^+|-].*[^+|-]$
```

Comment: Mine is incorrect because I missed '.' in the middle of the expression? I tested this **^[^+-].*[^+-]$** on [link](http://regexr.com/) and it works.

Comment: I believe you need `pipe` between `+` and `-` as well. But if it is working for you, it should be correct.